# add and subtract additional classes

Tags: javascript, html, class

im trying to add and subtract a class using java script im also using multiple classes here is my code

```
function enlargegreen() {

    document.getElementByClassName('playlist-player').className += "enlarge";
    document.getElementByClassName('playlist-player').className -= "shrink";

}
<div  class="playlist-player shrink green" onmousedown="enlargegreen()" ></div>
```

Im trying to subtract the shrink part and replace it with enlarge

Comment: See `classList` or use a framework like jQuery.

Comment: There's no `className` property on the collection returned by `getElementByClassName()`. You'll have to apply the extra classes to each element individually. If you do that with string concatenation rather than `classList` you'll have to use a space as a delimiter for each class.

Comment: There is no `getElementByClassName` method, there *is* a `getElementsByClassName`, which returns a collection of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".playlist-player").addClass("green test2").removeClass("playlist-player");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uk67u/)

[About addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[About removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

I made a quick fiddle where i used addClass() and removeClass() in my example. A little about both :

1 ) removeClass() : Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

2 ) addClass() : Adds the specified class(es) to each of the set of matched elements.

Comment: this works in the fiddle but not when i use it in dreamweaver and chrome :S

Comment: I made this fiddle while working in chrome, let me see if i can find the issue. You can just read up on the two functions and add the jQuery 1.9 and you will be fine.

Comment: Add the latest jquery in the header and wrap that function in $(document).ready(). Have you done this ?

Comment: Click the check mark that you must viewing on the left side of my answer and if possible then uprate the answer too. Thanks.

Comment: No sane person is going to use jQuery for 2 or 3 lines of JScript code. C'mon people. Stop this madness. Besides jQuery slows down the whole site.

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is an option you could simply use addClass (http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and removeClass (http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

It would then look like:

```
$('.playlist-player').addClass('enlarge');
$('.playlist-player').removeClass('shrink');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few <del>simple</del> js routines:

```
function addClass( element, name, remove ){
  if ( element.className ) {
    var re = new RegExp(
      '(^|\\s+)' + 
      name.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9])/gi, '\\$1') + 
      '(\\s+|$)',
      'g'
    );
    if ( remove ) {
      element.className = element.className.replace( re, '' );
    }
    else if ( !re.test( element.className ) ) {
      element.className += ' ' + name; 
    }
  }
  else if ( !remove ) {
    element.className = name;
  }
};

function removeClass( element, name ){
  return addClass( element, name, true );
};
```

<del>The above doesn't make a check for any special characters that might break the `RegExp` as part of the class name</del>. But then again, *in my opinion*, you should only really have `_` or `-` beyond letters and numbers.

#### update

I've added a bit of protection now, it should escape any non-alphanumeric character.

#### update 2

As zzzzBov correctly stated there was an error with not matching the end of the class name which should now be rectified. It also now checks before adding a class to make sure one didn't exist previously. I have also removed case-insensitivity.

I would be interested to know what issues `name.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9])/gi, '\\$1')` could cause, because apart from excessive escaping I'm not certain what could be a problem — within reason — this information would be of use to those finding this QA in the future.

Comment: "But then again you should only really have `_` or `-` beyond letters and numbers" [this is not true, classes are merely space-separated tokens with no other naming restrictions](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#classes). `$%^&*` would be a valid class, although it would likely cause issues with other libraries that make the same naive mistake as you have.

Comment: @zzzzBov Ah so I guess that stating my opinion, on top of an entirely correct answer is grounds for marking down? I would entirely disagree. You should only be using those separators, using anything else -- despite what the specifications might say -- is asking for trouble. What happens if any of the other characters you mention gain importance at a future date? Part of being a good webdev is knowing what to avoid, and forming your own opinion, rather than blindly following specs. Don't worry though, I'll make a change to my answer.

Comment: I voted down your post because the code you've provided is a naive implementation which will cause more harm than good if programmers choose to use it. The specification defines the edge case that code should be written for. It's the reason it's called the **specification**.

Comment: @zzzzBov In that case then should you not remove your downvote now? Considering after your first comment I have modified the code to support any extra character that may cause an issue.

Comment: @zzzzBov ah, and how about now?

Comment: You've still got a massive number of bugs, I'm not really willing to continue to debug your code. Some of the bugs include issues where you're adding the same class multiple times, or issues where you try to call `removeClass(elem, 'foo')` on an element with a class of `foobar`, there are other more obscure issues due to your naive regular expression escaping. **I highly recommend against anyone using this code to handle classes**.

Comment: @zzzzBov The kinder approach usually is just to leave a note about what you think the issues are, especially not referring to someone as naive, it is rather rude. It has nothing to do with naivety and everything to do with not allocating full focus or time on something that really is just to help another coder out with an idea which they should take and improve &mdash; at no point did I say this offering would be good enough to patch jQuery or the like -- in fact I stated it was simple. That aside I've updated my code, you were correct about the end-matching so thank you for that.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have a class named `playlist-player`. You have a class named `playlist-player shrink green` and your class names should not have spaces. And I think you should be using `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: there are 3 classes listed there , you can't have a space in a class name

Comment: I'm just copying what they wrote.

Comment: yeah realised this and theni tried `document.getElementByClassName('playlist-player shrink green').className += "playlist-player enlarge green";
 document.getElementByClassName('playlist-player enlarge green').className -= "playlist-player shrink green";` doesnt work either