# Does CSS (JavaScript) have something like symlink between DOM elements to prevent duplicate Content using Media queries?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, symlink

I am thinking, how to make website responsive, and in some cases I would prefer structure like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="mobile-only">Content</div>
    <div class="desktop-only">Content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

but **the Content** is always the same, so the idea is to have structure like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="mobile-only using-media-query" data-content-symlink="#content"></div>
    <div class="desktop-only using-media-query" data-content-symlink="#content"></div>
    <div id="symlinks" class="hidden">
      <div id="content">Content</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how this could be possible? Or is there any better workaround?

PS: I know about media queries, I want to prevent duplicate Content, which would be printed in both "mobile-only" and "desktop-only" version.

Comment: Repeating the exact same content twice makes no sense to begin with. And neither does your second proposed structure (even if something like that did exist) - you need only _one_ element that you format differently based on what screen size you are dealing with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change website design for mobile devices or browser resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217304/change-website-design-for-mobile-devices-or-browser-resize)

Comment: CSS has the @media selctors for switching styling based on whether it's print or screen and is also used to switch between mobile, tablet and desktop.

Comment: @CBroe You are right, twice content is hell, this I dont want. I want to find workaround to duplicate content. But something like "symlink idea" can open new doors when dealing with responsiveness. At least my layout definition would become  transparent...

Comment: _“But something like "symlink idea" can open new doors when dealing with responsiveness.”_ – sure, and a wrecking ball can open “new doors” in your home ... but that doesn’t mean it would make any sense or be an actual improvement.

Comment: @CBroe lol... nevermind, I am just brainstorming

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, I would suggest to use a Responsive Layout framework such as **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** that was developed by many smart folks over several years, and that will help you achieve what you want much easier. Basically you put the Content central (just once!), with styles to apply for different screen sizes (extra small, small, medium, large, extra large).

Comment: @peterB you are right, I am using SemanticUI. But the question is about something little bit different (about preventing Content duplication when layout for each device is too different).

Comment: I agree with @Mariyo that there is a use case for this symlink-like feature.  It reminds me of YAML's [alias nodes](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#71-alias-nodes).

Comment: A javascript solution that emulates symlinks can be found on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ttkaminski/pen/zYaKqKN).  The problem with this solution is that it can lead to CLS if the javascript isn't executed right away, and it clones the DOM, so not truly a "symlink".

Answer (score 1):

As the OP also asks for better workarounds, I suggest using the CSS `@media` query to change how the site looks on mobile.

<s>If you want different content by screen size, simply add and subtract classes that make divs either `display: none` or `display: whateveryounormallyuse`, like this:</s>

```
addClass(document.querySelector("#content-mobile"), "visible", false);
removeClass(document.querySelecto("#content-desktop"), "visible");
```

with the functions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281300/6634591) answer

But seeing as you want the same content twice, I'd suggest taking a look into
[CSS Media Queries (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). You can format your HTML elements completely different from desktop, align them in other ways, everything you can do with CSS - basically

Comment: You should avoid to link to w3schools, they had inaccuracies and false information in the past and still have. E.g. in your link they write that `@media screen and (min-width: 480px)` changes `[...] background-color if the viewport is 480 pixels wide or wider[...]`, this is partially right, but it will only change the background if the media type is `screen` and the view port is equal or greater then `480px`,   the `@media (min-width: 480px)` without the `screen and` would match their description.

Comment: you're right, I forgot why I linked them instead of MDN,changed the link, thanks! :)